# Hardhat, ether.js. TypeError: deployer.sendTransaction is not a function error. Trying to execute exactInput UniswapV3 function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, uniswap

Im trying to execute a swap to buy Uni using UniswapV3 interface.
It sends me this error related to the `sendTransaction()` function and I dont understand why as a lot of examples that I have seen use it this way.

Im using hardhat as you can see and calling the `getToken()` from another script and deploying on goerli network. Function to check UNI wallet `balnceOf()` at the end works fine.

Also what advice would you recommend me to improve my code?

This is the code:

```
const { ethers, getNamedAccounts, network } = require("hardhat")
const {abi: V3SwapRouterABI} = require('@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol/ISwapRouter.json')

const FEE_SIZE = 3

function encodePath(path, fees) {
    if (path.length != fees.length + 1) {
        throw new Error('path/fee lengths do not match')
    }

    let encoded = '0x'
    for (let i = 0; i < fees.length; i++) {
        // 20 byte encoding of the address
        encoded += path[i].slice(2)
        // 3 byte encoding of the fee
        encoded += fees[i].toString(16).padStart(2 * FEE_SIZE, '0')
    }
    // encode the final token
    encoded += path[path.length - 1].slice(2)

    return encoded.toLowerCase()
    }

async function getToken() {

    // const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + (60*10)
    const wethToken= "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"
    const Uni= "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984"
    const UniswapRouter="0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45"
    const path = encodePath([wethToken, Uni], [3000])
    console.log(path)
    
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const UniV3Contract = await ethers.getContractAt(
        V3SwapRouterABI,
        UniswapRouter,
        deployer
    )

    const params = {
        path: path,
        recipient:deployer,
        deadline: deadline,
        amountIn: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01'),
        amountOutMinimum: 0
    }

    const encodedData = UniV3Contract.interface.encodeFunctionData("exactInput", [params])

    const txArg = {
        to: UniswapRouter,
        from: deployer,
        data: encodedData,
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(1000000)
    }

    const tx = await deployer.sendTransaction(txArg)
    console.log('tx: ', tx)

    const IUni = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "IERC20",
        Uni,
        deployer
    )
    const UniBlance = await IUni.balanceOf(deployer)
    console.log(`Got ${UniBlance.toString()} UNI`)
}

module.exports = { getToken }
```

**Without using the hardhat enviorment:**

```
const {abi: V3SwapRouterABI} = require('@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol/ISwapRouter.json')
const { ethers } = require("ethers")
require("dotenv").config()

const INFURA_URL_TESTNET = process.env.INFURA_URL_TESTNET
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY
const WALLET_ADDRESS = process.env.WALLET_ADDRESS
// now you can call sendTransaction 


const wethToken= "0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6"
const Uni= "0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984"
const UniswapRouter="0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45"
const UniV3Contract = new ethers.Contract(
    UniswapRouter,
    V3SwapRouterABI
)

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(INFURA_URL_TESTNET)
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY)
const signer = wallet.connect(provider)


const FEE_SIZE = 3

function encodePath(path, fees) {
    if (path.length != fees.length + 1) {
        throw new Error('path/fee lengths do not match')
    }

    let encoded = '0x'
    for (let i = 0; i < fees.length; i++) {
        // 20 byte encoding of the address
        encoded += path[i].slice(2)
        // 3 byte encoding of the fee
        encoded += fees[i].toString(16).padStart(2 * FEE_SIZE, '0')
    }
    // encode the final token
    encoded += path[path.length - 1].slice(2)

    return encoded.toLowerCase()
    }

async function getToken() {

    const path = encodePath([wethToken, Uni], [3000])
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + (60*10)  

    const params = {
        path: path,
        recipient: WALLET_ADDRESS,
        deadline: deadline,
        amountIn: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01'),
        amountOutMinimum: 0
    }

    const encodedData = UniV3Contract.interface.encodeFunctionData("exactInput", [params])

    const txArg = {
        to: UniswapRouter,
        from: WALLET_ADDRESS,
        data: encodedData,
        gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(1000000)
    }

    const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(txArg)
    console.log('tx: ', tx)
    const receipt = tx.wait()
    console.log('receipt: ', receipt)

}

module.exports = { getToken }
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find documentation for `getNamedAccounts` but when I check the source code, I get this signature

```
getNamedAccounts: () => Promise<{
      [name: string]: Address;
    }>;
```

this just returns an array of account addresses and used in `hardhat.config.js`

```
namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
        default: 0, // by default take the first account as deployer
        1: 0,
    },
},
```

to send the transaction programmatically:

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(INFURA_TEST_URL);

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET);
const signer = wallet.connect(provider);
// now you can call sendTransaction
const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(txArg);
```

Comment: I have seen these code but I wanted to do it with the hardhat enviorment tools, but seeing it is enough complicated for me I tryed the code you provided. thanks!

Comment: Uploaded the post with the code provided and now its failing tx. https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xb0d5e4b491610b9db8d98cc938008ba2a4e1a06e67b05ed87ac6c0ca3ad61dab
Do you know what it could be? Im getting frustrated with this.